# Can a custom class loader be created for Java to conditionally load a class from JAR or from CLASS_PATH?

Tags: java, classloader, dynamic-class-loaders

We had a discussion at work about pros and cons of static (from a built JAR) vs dynamic (from separate location in CLASS_PATH) loading of Java libraries.

In the middle of that discussion, it occurred to me: regardless of which side is right, maybe there's a way to have your cake and eat it too:

- Have a default custom class loader for your organization
- Class loader - when loading a specific library - checks a configuration that, for every library (or app+library combo for more granularity), contains a flag that determines if the library is to be loaded statically from the JAR or dynamically from CLASS_PATH
- The apps all get built with the library classes in their JARs (default "backup" version of the library to use if you don't want to dynamically load new library version)
- If you wish your library to be loaded statically (e.g. because new version is incompatible with older one, or just to eliminate change risk if warranted), you set the configuration flag for that library to true.
- If instead your change risk is zero/low, you set the flag to false; and allow the library to be loaded dynamically, thus allowing you to release new versions of the library that get picked up by ALL apps without re-compilation and re-release (obviously, the apps would need to all be tested with new library for this to be anything but a minefield of bugs approach).

Whether my idea is good or bad, **what I would like to know is, whether my second bullet point is even technically feasible with Java (say 1.8+), and if so, what would be involved in implementing it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. I will assume Java 8 for this answer  , as I have yet to familiarize myself with the capabilities of Java 9's [Module System](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/).

The main idea is straightforward--a `ClassLoader` whose `loadClass(String, boolean)` implementation adheres to the following "protocol":

1. If the class name argument refers to a system class, delegate loading to your parent loader and return. Otherwise proceed.
2. Does the name, according to your configuration, refer to an application class? If so proceed to step 2.1, otherwise to 3.

   1. Get the application "search path" (the filesystem path of the JAR file itself according to the requirements in the question).
   2. Attempt to find, in an implementation-specific manner (by means of e.g. path resolution against the search path's entries), a class resource below the search path that matches the name argument. If such a resource exists, proceed to step 5, otherwise to 3.
3. For each known library not yet examined, sorted by descending priority:

   1. Does the name refer to a class of that library? If so continue; otherwise return to 3.
   2. Get the search path for the particular library.
   3. Attempt to find a class resource under the search path that matches the name argument. If successful, proceed to step 5, otherwise return to step 3.
4. If no matching class resource was established in step 2 or 3, raise an exception. Otherwise continue.
5. Retrieve the content of the resource, delegate to `defineClass` and `resolveClass` as appropriate, and return the new class.

---

Below is a (pretty ugly) sample implementation of such a `ClassLoader`.

Assumptions:

- A *module* is an *application* or a *library*.
- A module comprises a known set of classes; in other words, a module "is aware of its contents".
- An application uses zero or more libraries.
- Multiple logical applications may be running on the same JVM.
- A `Configuration` communicates to its `ClassLoader`:

  - The "current" application requesting class loading.
  - Mappings between applications and search paths.
  - Mappings between library-application pairs and search paths.
- Multiple loaders may use (the persisted representation of) the same configuration.

---

```
package com.example.q45313762;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.CodeSource;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public final class ConfigurableClasspathClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {

    public interface Configuration {

        interface Module {

            String getName();

            String getVersion();

            boolean includes(String resourceName);

        }

        interface Library extends Module {}

        interface Application extends Module {}

        enum LoadingMode {
            STATIC, DYNAMIC;
        }

        Application getCurrentApplication();

        Iterable<URL> getLibrarySearchPath(Library lib, LoadingMode mode, Application app);

        Iterable<URL> getApplicationSearchPath(Application app);

        Iterable<Library> getApplicationLibraries(Application app);

    }

    public static final class SimpleStaticConfiguration implements Configuration {

        private static abstract class SimpleModule implements Module {

            private final String name, version;
            private final Predicate<String> resourceNameMatcher;

            private SimpleModule(String name, String version, Predicate<String> resourceNameMatcher) {
                requireNoneNull(name, version, resourceNameMatcher);
                name = name.trim();
                version = version.trim();
                if (name.isEmpty() || version.isEmpty()) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("arguments must not be empty.");
                }
                this.name = name;
                this.version = version;
                this.resourceNameMatcher = resourceNameMatcher;
            }

            @Override
            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            @Override
            public String getVersion() {
                return version;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean includes(String resourceName) {
                if (resourceName == null) {
                    return false;
                }
                return resourceNameMatcher.test(resourceName);
            }

            @Override
            public final int hashCode() {
                final int prime = 31;
                int result = 1;
                result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
                result = prime * result + ((resourceNameMatcher == null) ? 0 : resourceNameMatcher.hashCode());
                result = prime * result + ((version == null) ? 0 : version.hashCode());
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            public final boolean equals(Object obj) {
                if (this == obj) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (obj == null) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (!(obj instanceof SimpleModule)) {
                    return false;
                }
                SimpleModule other = (SimpleModule) obj;
                if (name == null) {
                    if (other.name != null) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else if (!name.equals(other.name)) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (resourceNameMatcher == null) {
                    if (other.resourceNameMatcher != null) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else if (!resourceNameMatcher.equals(other.resourceNameMatcher)) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (version == null) {
                    if (other.version != null) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else if (!version.equals(other.version)) {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }

        }

        public static final class SimpleLibrary extends SimpleModule implements Library {

            public SimpleLibrary(String name, String version, Predicate<String> resourceNameMatcher) {
                super(name, version, resourceNameMatcher);
            }

        }

        public static final class SimpleApplication extends SimpleModule implements Application {

            public SimpleApplication(String name, String version, Predicate<String> resourceNameMatcher) {
                super(name, version, resourceNameMatcher);
            }

        }

        private static final class ModuleRegistry {

            private static abstract class Key {

                private final Module module;

                private Key(Module module) {
                    requireNoneNull(module);
                    requireNoneNull(module.getName(), module.getVersion());
                    this.module = module;
                }

                private Module getModule() {
                    return module;
                }

            }

            private static final class LibraryKey extends Key {

                private final LoadingMode mode;
                private final Application app;

                private LibraryKey(Library lib, LoadingMode mode, Application app) {
                    super(lib);
                    requireNoneNull(mode);
                    requireNoneNull(app);
                    this.mode = mode;
                    this.app = app;
                }

                private Library getLibrary() {
                    return (Library) super.getModule();
                }

                private LoadingMode getLoadingMode() {
                    return mode;
                }

                private Application getApplication() {
                    return app;
                }

                @Override
                public int hashCode() {
                    final int prime = 31;
                    int result = 1;
                    Library lib = getLibrary();
                    result = prime * result + ((lib == null) ? 0 : lib.hashCode());
                    result = prime * result + ((mode == null) ? 0 : mode.hashCode());
                    result = prime * result + ((app == null) ? 0 : app.hashCode());
                    return result;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                    if (this == obj) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (obj == null) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (!(obj instanceof LibraryKey)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    LibraryKey other = (LibraryKey) obj;
                    Library thisLib = getLibrary(), othersLib = other.getLibrary();
                    if (thisLib == null) {
                        if (othersLib != null) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (!thisLib.equals(othersLib)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (mode != other.mode) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (app == null) {
                        if (other.app != null) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (!app.equals(other.app)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }

            }

            private static final class ApplicationKey extends Key {

                private ApplicationKey(Application app) {
                    super(app);
                }

                private Application getApplication() {
                    return (Application) super.getModule();
                }

                @Override
                public int hashCode() {
                    final int prime = 31;
                    int result = 1;
                    Application app = getApplication();
                    result = prime * result + ((app == null) ? 0 : app.hashCode());
                    return result;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                    if (this == obj) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (obj == null) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (!(obj instanceof ApplicationKey)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    ApplicationKey other = (ApplicationKey) obj;
                    Application thisApp = getApplication(), othersApp = other.getApplication();
                    if (thisApp == null) {
                        if (othersApp != null) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (!thisApp.equals(othersApp)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }

            }

            private static final class Value {

                private final Set<URL> searchPath;

                private Value(URL... searchPath) {
                    requireNoneNull((Object) searchPath);
                    if (searchPath == null || searchPath.length == 0) {
                        this.searchPath = EMPTY_SEARCH_PATH;
                    }
                    else {
                        this.searchPath = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(searchPath));
                        Iterator<URL> itr = this.searchPath.iterator();
                        while (itr.hasNext()) {
                            URL searchPathEntry = itr.next();
                            String proto = searchPathEntry.getProtocol();
                            if ("file".equals(proto) || "jar".equals(proto)) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            itr.remove();
                        }
                        verify();
                    }
                }

                private Set<URL> getSearchPath() {
                    verify();
                    return (searchPath == EMPTY_SEARCH_PATH) ? searchPath : Collections.unmodifiableSet(searchPath);
                }

                private void verify() {
                    Iterator<URL> itr = searchPath.iterator();
                    while (itr.hasNext()) {
                        try {
                            if (!Files.exists(Paths.get(itr.next().toURI()))) {
                                itr.remove();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (IllegalArgumentException | URISyntaxException | SecurityException e) {
                            itr.remove();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public int hashCode() {
                    final int prime = 31;
                    int result = 1;
                    result = prime * result + ((searchPath == null) ? 0 : searchPath.hashCode());
                    return result;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                    if (this == obj) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (obj == null) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (!(obj instanceof Value)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    Value other = (Value) obj;
                    if (searchPath == null) {
                        if (other.searchPath != null) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (!searchPath.equals(other.searchPath)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }

            }

            private final Map<Key, Value> m = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            private Supplier<Application> appProvider;

            private ModuleRegistry() {
            }

            private ModuleRegistry(ModuleRegistry mr) {
                m.putAll(mr.m);
                appProvider = mr.appProvider;
            }

            private void putLibraryEntry(Library lib, LoadingMode mode, Application app, URL... searchPath) {
                m.put(new LibraryKey(lib, mode, app), new Value(searchPath));
            }

            private void putApplicationEntry(Application app, URL... searchPath) {
                m.put(new ApplicationKey(app), new Value(searchPath));
            }

            private Set<Library> getLibraries(Application app) {
                Set<Library> ret = null;
                for (Key k : m.keySet()) {
                    if (!(k instanceof LibraryKey)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    LibraryKey lk = (LibraryKey) k;
                    if (lk.getApplication().equals(app)) {
                        if (ret == null) {
                            ret = new LinkedHashSet<>();
                        }
                        ret.add(lk.getLibrary());
                    }
                }
                if (ret == null) {
                    ret = NO_LIBS;
                }
                return ret;
            }

            private Set<URL> getLibrarySearchPath(Library lib, LoadingMode mode, Application app) {
                Set<URL> ret = EMPTY_SEARCH_PATH;
                Value v = m.get(new LibraryKey(lib, mode, app));
                if (mode == LoadingMode.DYNAMIC && (v == null || v.getSearchPath().isEmpty())) {
                    v = m.get(new LibraryKey(lib, LoadingMode.STATIC, app));
                }
                if (v != null) {
                    ret = v.getSearchPath();
                }
                return ret;
            }

            private Set<URL> getApplicationSearchPath(Application app) {
                Set<URL> ret = EMPTY_SEARCH_PATH;
                Value v = m.get(new ApplicationKey(app));
                if (v != null) {
                    ret = v.getSearchPath();
                }
                return ret;
            }

            private Supplier<Application> getApplicationProvider() {
                return appProvider;
            }

            private void setApplicationProvider(Supplier<Application> appProvider) {
                requireNoneNull(appProvider);
                requireNoneNull(appProvider.get());
                this.appProvider = appProvider;
            }

            private void clear() {
                m.clear();
            }

        }

        public static final class Builder {

            private final ModuleRegistry registry = new ModuleRegistry();

            private Builder() {
            }

            public synchronized Builder withLibrary(Library lib, LoadingMode mode, Application app, URL... searchPath) {
                registry.putLibraryEntry(lib, mode, app, searchPath);
                return this;
            }

            public synchronized Builder withApplication(Application app, URL... searchPath) {
                registry.putApplicationEntry(app, searchPath);
                return this;
            }

            public synchronized Builder withApplicationProvider(Supplier<Application> appProvider) {
                registry.setApplicationProvider(appProvider);
                return this;
            }

            public synchronized SimpleStaticConfiguration build() {
                SimpleStaticConfiguration ret = new SimpleStaticConfiguration(this);
                registry.clear();
                return ret;
            }

            public synchronized Builder reset() {
                registry.clear();
                return this;
            }

        }

        public static final Set<URL> EMPTY_SEARCH_PATH = Collections.emptySet();
        private static final Set<Library> NO_LIBS = Collections.emptySet();

        public static Builder newBuilder() {
            return new Builder();
        }

        private final ModuleRegistry registry;

        private SimpleStaticConfiguration(Builder b) {
            registry = new ModuleRegistry(b.registry);
        }

        @Override
        public Application getCurrentApplication() {
            return registry.getApplicationProvider().get();
        }

        @Override
        public Iterable<URL> getLibrarySearchPath(Library lib, LoadingMode mode, Application app) {
            return registry.getLibrarySearchPath(lib, mode, app);
        }

        @Override
        public Iterable<URL> getApplicationSearchPath(Application app) {
            return registry.getApplicationSearchPath(app);
        }

        @Override
        public Iterable<Library> getApplicationLibraries(Application app) {
            return registry.getLibraries(app);
        }

    }

    private static final String JAVA_HOME_PROP = System.getProperty("java.home");

    private static void requireNoneNull(Object... args) {
        if (args != null) {
            for (Object o : args) {
                Objects.requireNonNull(o);
            }
        }
    }

    private final Lock readLock, writeLock;
    private Configuration cfg;

    {
        ReadWriteLock rwl = new ReentrantReadWriteLock(false);
        readLock = rwl.readLock();
        writeLock = rwl.writeLock();
    }

    public ConfigurableClasspathClassLoader(Configuration cfg, ClassLoader parent) {
        super(new URL[0], parent);
        setConfiguration(cfg);
    }

    public void setConfiguration(Configuration cfg) {
        requireNoneNull(cfg);
        try {
            writeLock.lock();
            this.cfg = cfg;
        }
        finally {
            writeLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        if (name == null) {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException(name);
        }
        synchronized (getClassLoadingLock(name)) {
            Class<?> ret;
            Class<?> self = getClass();
            if (self.getName().equals(name)) {
                // no need to "reload" our own class
                return self;
            }
            ret = findLoadedClass(name);
            if (ret != null) {
                // already loaded
                return ret;
            }
            // unknown
            ret = findClass(name);
            if (resolve) {
                resolveClass(ret);
            }
            return ret;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        // perform a search on the global classpath (obviously far from ideal)
        Enumeration<URL> allMatches;
        String modifiedName = name.replace(".", "/").concat(".class");
        try {
            allMatches = getResources(modifiedName);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException(name);
        }
        Set<URL> filteredMatches = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        while (allMatches.hasMoreElements()) {
            URL match = allMatches.nextElement();
            if (match.getPath().replaceFirst("file:", "").startsWith(JAVA_HOME_PROP)) {
                // probably a bootstrap classpath class - these are off limits to us
                return getParent().loadClass(name);
            }
            // candidate match
            filteredMatches.add(match);
        }
        if (!filteredMatches.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                readLock.lock();
                BiFunction<Configuration.Module, Iterable<URL>, URL[]> matcher = (module, searchPath) -> {
                    URL[] ret = null;
                    if (module.includes(name)) {
                        outer: for (URL searchPathEntry : searchPath) {
                            for (URL filteredMatch : filteredMatches) {
                                if (filteredMatch != null && filteredMatch.getPath().replaceFirst("file:", "")
                                        .startsWith(searchPathEntry.getPath())) {
                                    ret = new URL[] { filteredMatch, searchPathEntry };
                                    break outer;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return ret;
                };
                Configuration.Application app = cfg.getCurrentApplication();
                URL matchedClassResource = null, matchingSearchPath = null;
                if (app != null) {
                    // try an application search path match
                    URL[] tmp = matcher.apply(app, cfg.getApplicationSearchPath(app));
                    if (tmp != null) {
                        matchedClassResource = tmp[0];
                        matchingSearchPath = tmp[1];
                    }
                    else {
                        // try matching against the search path of any library "known to" app
                        for (Configuration.Library lib : cfg.getApplicationLibraries(app)) {
                            tmp = matcher.apply(lib,
                                    cfg.getLibrarySearchPath(lib, Configuration.LoadingMode.DYNAMIC, app));
                            if (tmp != null) {
                                matchedClassResource = tmp[0];
                                matchingSearchPath = tmp[1];
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (matchedClassResource != null) {
                        // matched - load
                        byte[] classData = readClassData(matchedClassResource);
                        return defineClass(name, classData, 0, classData.length,
                                constructClassDomain(matchingSearchPath));
                    }
                }
            }
            finally {
                readLock.unlock();
            }
        }
        throw new ClassNotFoundException(name);
    }

    private byte[] readClassData(URL classResource) {
        try (InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(classResource.openStream());
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            while (in.available() > 0) {
                out.write(in.read());
            }
            return out.toByteArray();

        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
        }
    }

    private ProtectionDomain constructClassDomain(URL codeSourceLocation) {
        CodeSource cs = new CodeSource(codeSourceLocation, (Certificate[]) null);
        return new ProtectionDomain(cs, getPermissions(cs), this, null);
    }

}
```

---

Notes:

- Search paths registered with the loader must be subsets (subtrees) of the *effective* classpath ("java.class.path" property). Furthermore, "fat JARs" are not supported.
- I could not include a usage example due to post length constraints. I will provide one via gist if requested.